# Error trying to use LibreOffice COM library `com.sun.star.ServiceManager': Access denied

Tags: php, com, libreoffice, shell-exec, openoffice.org

I am trying to use the libreOffice library using PHP.
When I run the code from the console it works fine, but when I run it via the browser it fails. The error is "Failed to create COM object `com.sun.star.ServiceManager': Access Denied".

Any way to give permissions to be able to execute that COM library? I am using an IIS server.

I have tried to do a shell_exec() but it gives the same error.
I'll give you an example of the code.

```
<?php
//test.php
$as = shell_exec('php test_LO.php 2>&1');
var_dump($as);
```

```
<?php
//test_LO.php

  $serviceManager = new COM("com.sun.star.ServiceManager");
```

Comment: Why do you need to use Office on the server side? What is your end goal?

Comment: I need to make some modifications to a spreadsheet, I have tried to use some php libraries like (https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet) but they don't work for me since the spreadsheet contains macros and formulas.

Therefore I decided to use openoffice's own API, which can be used using the php COM libraries.

Comment: If you deal with open XML documents you may consider using the Open XML SDK instead. Or third-party components designed for the server-side execution.

Comment: I have my project in PHP and mysql. I would like to be able to use this own technology. I have never worked with .net.

Comment: You do not need .net to deal with open XML documents - they are just zip archives with files inside. You can parse them on your own or find any library which does that for you.